# How do we know that water has [H+] = 10^-7?

Tags: acid-base, ph, concentration

In the derivation of $K_\mathrm{w}$, the ionic product of water, it is stated that

$$[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] = K_\mathrm{w}$$

and substituting $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-7}$ we can find that $K_\mathrm{w} = 10^{-14}$.

How do we know, though, that $[\ce{H+}] = 10^{-7}$? And why is $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}]$?

Because the water is electrically neutral.

In general, for all solutions, the sum of the concentration of each ion, multiplied by the ion's respective charge, must be zero.

> How do we know $[\ce{H+}] = 10^{-7}$?

This is found by experimentally by determining $K_\mathrm{w}$ and substituting, or by measuring the pH.

For details see: Bandura, A. V.; Lvov, S. N. The Ionization Constant of Water over Wide Ranges of Temperature and Density. *J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data* **2006,** *35* (1), 15–30. [DOI: 10.1063/1.1928231](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1928231).

Comment: Thanks ! But
How do we know concentration of H+ is 10^-7 while deriving Kw  ?

Comment: $K_w$ is measured. It does depend on temperature. pH of pure water is 7.47 at 0 degrees C and 6.14 at 100 degrees C. http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/kw.html